# NSMutableArray rearrange

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am parsing an XML and getting the details of members. In that I am getting the status code 0(offline)  or 1(online) of member. I stored the this values into an NSMutableArray. Now I want to display first online members and then offline members.

How can I accomplish this ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use SortDescriptors to tell how you sorting will work. then just call:

```
[yourNSMutableArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:yourSortDescriptor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting array with using function:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [dict.allKeys sortedArrayUsingFunction:alfabetSort context:NULL];

NSInteger alfabetSort(id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
    return [num1 compare:num2];
}
```